# Need help is excluding a package containing junits using maven profile

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have a scenario where i need to exclude certain tests in a module from running during the compilation. For that, i have a created a profile in that module's pom.xml as shown below,

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>excludeTests</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>excludeTests</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>com/abc/def/MyPackage</exclude>
                            </excludes>

                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

In the command line, I am running the below command,

```
mvn clean test -DexcludeTests=true
```

The junit classes present under 'MyPackage' is still getting executed. Is my profile really getting picked. Please help me here to exclude the junits from this package while building.

Comment: Why skipping the tests? Do they not work? If so you should remove them because they have no value ...Furthermore depending on JUnit you can annotate them with `@Ignore` ...

Comment: They work. No issues there. As i mentioned, i just need to check health of my code base. The test cases which i want to ignore is not managed by our team. I just need to check my code and its test cases only.

Comment: So why skipping the tests if you like check the health of your code? Sounds like a contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach to do this in Maven is via profiles but if you don't want to touch the `pom.xml`, you can create a `@Rule` (in Junit 4) to skip tests based on some property you set in command line or as an environment variable (useful for CI).

Here's an example:

```
public class SkippableTestRule implements TestRule {

   private final boolean SKIP_TESTS = System.getProperty( "skipSelectedTests", false );

   @Override
   public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
        if ( SKIP_TESTS && skippablePackage()) {
            return new SkipTest();
        }
        return base;
    }

    private static class SkipTest extends Statement {

        private SkipTest() {
        }

        @Override
        public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
            Assume.assumeTrue( "Skipping test", false );
        }
    }
}
```

Now that you have defined this rule, you can apply it to a test class this way:

```
class MyTests {

    @Rule
    public SkippableTestRule rule = new SkSkippableTestRule();
}
```

Now all the tests in the class will be ignored when you run the build with:

```
mvn -DargLine="-DskipSelectedTests=true"
```

If this is not good enough, [you can create a Test Unit runner instead](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-4-custom-runners). This will give you more control on which test class is running.

For JUnit 5, you can [do something similar with extensions](https://reflectoring.io/conditional-junit4-junit5-tests/#assumptions-for-all-test-methods-with-junit-5).

Alternatively, you can [create a profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) where you configure the tests in a different way:

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.12.4</version>
   <configuration>
     <excludes>
       <exclude>**/acme/package/</exclude>
     </excludes>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

You can also define an `excludes` pattern. See the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) for more details.

The profiles will look something like this:

```xml
<profiles>
 <profile>
  <id>default-profile</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.4</version>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
</profile> 
</profile>
  <profile>
    <id>exclude-tests</id>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/acme/package</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </profile>
</profiles>
...
```

You can then run the specific profile with:

```
mvn test -P exclude-tests
```

Comment: i am looking for a way without touching the pom file. Can we pass some arguement to mvn command to ignore few tests

Comment: This is the best maven can do from the command line (as far as I know): https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/single-test.html

Comment: You can probably achieve the same result using a JUnit 4 rule or a JUnit 5 extension. I've updated my asnwer.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some ideas